# jQuery add html to original-title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a button which looks like this:

```
<a class="buttonS bDefault tipN" id="customerBasket" original-title="<ul class='shoppingBasket'></ul>" href="#"><span class="icos-cart3"></span></a>
```

Its a tooltip and I want to append list-items to the class `shoppingBasket`.

I've tried by doing the following:

```
$('.shoppingBasket ul').append(<li><span class=\'basketPic\'>Test</span><span class=\'basketName\'>Test123</span></li>);
```

But I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to put your appended string inside double quotes `" "`

Comment: Other than the double quotes, The problem is that you are using `$('.shoppingBasket ul').append()` and you should use `$('ul.shoppingBasket').append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your quotes:

```
$('ul.shoppingBasket').append("<li><span class='basketPic'>Test</span><span class='basketName'>Test123</span></li>");
```

EDIT after getting more info:

You're wanting to update an attribute, which is more complicated than just appending something to a dom element. But, you should be able to do it. Try something like this:

```
$button_title = $('.buttonS').attr('original-title');
$('body').append('<div id="cart-holder" style="display:none;">' + $button_title + '</div>');
$('#cart-holder ul.shoppingBasket').append('<li><span class=\'basketPic\'>Test</span><span class=\'basketName\'>Test123</span></li>');
$('.buttonS').attr('original-title', $('#cart-holder').html());
$('#cart-holder').remove();
```

This will add a div to the body with the HTML in `original-title`, append your HTML to it, set the `original-title` to it, then remove the element it just made. You'll likely have to tweak it to get the effect you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayuGE/2/)

Comment: Now the error disappeared but the list-item is still not getting added

Comment: Your selector was also out of place based on your HTML. I edited the code, try it now.

Comment: Still nothing :/ Maybe its because I have the html inside a `original-title=""`?

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realize it was in the `original-title` attribute. Since it's not a dom element you can't use `append()` on it. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I use tipsy with HTML turned on, and want to add list-items inside of it. So basically a tooltip :)

Comment: See my edit, should give you what you want with some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `append()` method accepts a string. And you **should** always add a string to its parameter. Otherwise it won't work for you and you'll get this error.

```
append("<li><span class='basketPic'>Test</span><span class='basketName'>Test123</span></li>")
```

This would do it. Otherwise, it won't work.